# Haskell FFI how to take an address of the local value

Tags: haskell, ffi

I try to work with this simple C-code from Haskell:

```
time_t rawTime = time( NULL );
struct tm* timeInfo = localtime( &rawTime );  /* Using address of a local variable */
printf( "The current date is: %s", asctime( timeInfo ) );
```

So I write:

```
data CTmStruct = CTmStruct
type CTmStructPtr = Ptr CTmStruct

foreign import ccall "time"      c_time      :: Ptr CTime    -> IO CTime
foreign import ccall "localtime" c_localtime :: Ptr CTime    -> IO CTmStructPtr
foreign import ccall "asctime"   c_asctime   :: CTmStructPtr -> CString

main :: IO ()
main = do
    rawTime <- c_time nullPtr
    tmStructPtr <- c_localtime ???  -- How to get an address of rawTime?
    print $ c_asctime tmStructPtr
```

So how can I get an address of a local value `rawTime` for putting it as an argument of a `c_localtime` function? I've read documentation to `Foreign` module, but I didn't find answer for this question. I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to pass a C struct across the FFI barrier. Pass a pointer, instead; if you need to access fields in the structure, you'll need to write C functions which do the access. This is so that GHC does not need to know about the memory layout and alignment your C compiler chooses for your struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do:

```
import Foreign.C.String
import Foreign.Marshal.Alloc

-- Your declarations and foreign bindings here

getTime :: IO String
getTime = do
    p <- malloc
    c_time p
    tmPtr <- c_localtime p
    str <- peekCString $ c_asctime tmPtr
    free p
    return str

main :: IO ()
main = do
    currentTime <- getTime
    putStrLn currentTime
```

The key is using `malloc` and `free`, you explicitly allocate the space, pass it to `c_time` to set the contents, then `c_localtime` to format it as a `CTmStruct`, then pass that to `c_asctime` to convert to a `CString`, marshal back to a Haskell `String` with `peekCString`, and finally free the pointer used to get the time.

---

I guess I should have realized this sooner, but a better solution would be to use `alloca`:

```
getTime :: IO String
getTime = alloca $ \p -> do
    c_time p
    tm <- c_localtime p
    peekCString $ c_astime tm
```

Which is safer, shorter, and easier.  The `alloca` function does the allocation and freeing of the pointer for you, all you have to do is use it.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! I've read about `alloca`, but your example explained me how to use it.